# XPath - Just the first element for each of the second level elements

Tags: xpath

Using this as an example:

```
<root>
  <gramps name="Bill">
    <him name="Bill Jr">
      <kid name="Bill III"/>
    </him>
  </gramps>
  <gramps name="Tom">
    <him name="Al">
      <kid name="Al Jr"/>
    </him>
  </gramps>
  <gramps name="Bob">
    <him name="Bob Jr">
      <kid name="Sam"/>
    </him>
  </gramps>
  <store name="Tom's"/>
  <store name="Bill's"/>
  <store name="Pete's"/>
</root>
```

I can get all of the second level elements with:

```
/*/*
```

I can get the names for all of the second level elements, `gramps store`, with:

```
distinct-values(/*/*/name())
```

How can I get just the first element for each of the second level elements resulting in:

```
  <gramps name="Bill">
    <him name="Bill Jr">
      <kid name="Bill III"/>
    </him>
  <store name="Tom's"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check at each name if there are previous with the same name:

```
/*/*[not(preceding-sibling::*/name() = name())]
```

Or, probably faster, find the first for each name:

```
for $name in distinct-values(/*/*/name()) return /*/*[name() = $name][1]
```

Comment: For a larger example the times match your statement. XPath: 1500 sec.
XQuery: 1.5 sec.